# What would be the best way to compare SQL DATE using months and year

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005, date, datetime, comparison

Good Day Everyone,

Today I'am facing some problems about Date Comparison, i have Set of Data with SQL Date Time with Them

[image: Sample Data]

If i want to retrieve all the ID's from a Specific Month and Specific Year

> (ex. All ID's that has a Date of Sepetember 2013)

i use this kind of code in the where clause

```
(DATENAME(MONTH,PHI.fld_LoanDate)) =  (DATENAME(MONTH,@month))
    AND
(DATEPART(YEAR,PHI.fld_LoanDate)) = (DATEPART(YEAR,@year))
```

but as of now i'am encountering some bugs maybe because of the Ugly comparisons in Date

so i would like to ask some help on how would i improve that code or if you can give me a better way to compare date using month and Year

Thanks :)

**EDIT:
  Month and Year are given by the user, and there are also some queries that i use like this

```
(DATENAME(MONTH,PHI.fld_LoanDate)) =  (DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD (MONTH,-4,@month + '2000')))  
  AND
    (DATEPART(YEAR,PHI.fld_LoanDate)) = (DATEPART(YEAR,@YEAR1))
```

Because i need to Subtract some months in a specific date that was given by the USer.

any better way would be Highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be better to just use a range query:

```
PHI.fld_LoanDate >= '20130901' and
PHI.fld_LoanDate < '20131001'
```

In this way, if there's potentially an index on `fld_LoanDate` it could be used by the above query.

---

Having seen edits - even if the values are supplied by the user, it's easy enough to compute a start and end date for the above comparison:

```
DECLARE @StartDate datetime
DECLARE @EndDate datetime

SET @StartDate = DATEADD(year,@Year - 1900,DATEADD(month,@Month - 1,'19000101'))
SET @EndDate = DATEADD(month,1,@StartDate)
```

and then use:

```
PHI.fld_LoanDate >= @StartDate and
PHI.fld_LoanDate < @EndDate
```

I'm not sure why you're obsessed with comparing date values by name but it's unlikely to be the best way to do things.

---

One final trick if the above are still not sufficient. This one won't allow you to use an index but does simplify some processes - you can do:

```
DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,0,PHI.fld_LoanDate),0)
```

Which rounds the date in `fld_LoanDate` down to the nearest 1st of the month.

Comment: my problem sir is that the month and year are given by the user. how can i use the range? please look at the **edit in my question because sometimes i need also to subtract 4 months based on the given month of the user thank you :)

Comment: how would i use this code for comparison?                                       
                                                            
`DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,0,PHI.fld_LoanDate),0) = @month(this is varchar 'September')+@year(this is varchar '2013')`?

im sorry sir if im obsessed in using Strings, I'm just a Starter in coding here in t-sql